# Does Zend\Authentication offer a way to check if an identity exists?

Tags: php, authentication, zend-framework2

Its simple enough to use Zend\Authentication to authenticate against a DB:

```
$isAuthenticated = $this->getAuthService($db)->getAdapter()
    ->setIdentity($this->request->getPost('username'))
    ->setCredential($this->request->getPost('password'))
    ->authenticate()
    ->isValid()
    ;
```

But this just returns a Boolean value if authentication was successful. Does Zend\Authentication offer a way to check if the identity is present in a DB and return this info as well? I could just do an sql query first to see if its in the DB, but before I do that I wanted to be sure there wasn't an in box solution the class offered for this.

This way I could have an "Incorrect password please try again" message vs "User account does not exist" . Or I could just say that not displaying this info is a security feature and not bother :P

Comment: Don't give out different error messages. Just say "It worked" and "It didn't work". You don't want anyone to be able to check if a specific user-account exists. That's a bad thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have the code. And you can use as this:

```
// inside of AuthController / loginAction
$result = $this->auth->authenticate($adapter);

switch ($result->getCode()) {

case Result::FAILURE_IDENTITY_NOT_FOUND:
    /** do stuff for nonexistent identity **/
    break;

case Result::FAILURE_CREDENTIAL_INVALID:
    /** do stuff for invalid credential **/
    break;

case Result::SUCCESS:
    /** do stuff for successful authentication **/
    break;

default:
    /** do stuff for other failure **/
    break;
}
```

Check the Authenticacion document http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.authentication.intro.html